How to interpret the induction principle of identity type (J rule)?
I'm trying hard to get some intuition behind induction principle of Id type, especially why we only need to consider the refl case. Now I have the following understanding:
(Using the based version J rule)
In general, an induction principle looks like:
$$C(a_1) \rightarrow C(a_2) \rightarrow ... \rightarrow \underset{(x:A)}{\Large{\Pi}}C(x)$$
Where $a_1,a_2,...$ should be all the canonical terms of $A$ .
Identity type should be similar:
$$C(a, refl) \rightarrow C(a_1, p_1) \rightarrow C(a_2, p_2) \rightarrow ...\underset{(x:A)}{\Large{\Pi}}\underset{(p:a=_Ax)}{\Large{\Pi}}C(x,p)$$
$a_i$ should be all the terms which (propositional, we're defining) equal to $a$ and $p_i$ their proofs (for a certain $a_i$ there may be more than one proof). The difficulty is we don't know how $a_i/p_i$ look like and they vary depend on context (example: $C(x+y, refl) \rightarrow C(y+x, p_1) \rightarrow C(x+y+0, p_2) \rightarrow ...)$
But we know
$$(\forall C)(C(a) \leftrightarrow C(a_i))$$
given $a=a_i$ (indiscernibility of identicals). If we extend it a bit, not only every $a_i$ is as good as $a$, but also $(a_i, p_i)$ is as good as $(a, refl)$, then the above will collapse into J:
$$C(a, refl) \rightarrow \underset{(x:A)}{\Large{\Pi}}\underset{(p:a=_Ax)}{\Large{\Pi}}C(x,p)$$
So the canonical terms of Id not only include $(a, refl)$, but also terms that are indistinguishable from it, thus "represented" by it as well.
So my question: is it a valid interpretation? Given its informality, I don't have enough confident..

The general form of an induction principle need not mention canonical terms, only constructors. That is, in order to prove something about every element of (the total space of) a (non-recursive) inductive family, it suffices to prove it for every constructor of the family.
For definiteness, let us consider the based identity type $a =_A -$ at some point $a : A$, seen as an indexed inductive family $A \to \mathrm{Type}$. This family is generated by the single constructor
$$\mathrm{refl} : a =_A a$$
Since there's only one constructor, the induction principle says that, in order to construct $C(b, p)$ for all $b : A$, $p : a =_A b$, it suffices to give $C(a, \mathrm{refl})$. This is precisely the $J$ rule.

Thanks. Do you mean that I should not consider terms as 'pre exist' elements, they only exist after construction, so that the constructors are the only things I need to concern?

I don't know what you mean by "exist", but if that intuition helps you, sure. I am only describing the formal syntax of type theory.

I know the formal syntax and that induction principle is derived from constructors. But I just don't understand what exactly means by 'the family generated by the single constructor refl'. Take a concrete example: the family of $x =_N -$, which is generated by the single constructor $refl: x=_N x$. But using cong (derived from J from another family) and the induction princple of natrual number, we can get a proof of $p: x=_N x+0$. Then what's the relationship between $refl$ and $p$? This proof does not involve the $refl: x=_N x$ at all, how is the proof generated by it?

Note that it is not correct to say that induction principles state that, 'something that holds for all canonical terms holds universally.' For $ℕ$ that would be some sort of ω-rule $C(0) → C(1) → C(2) → \ldots → Π_n C(n)$. If you could even state this properly, it wouldn't be a theorem, and there are models where it's false. This point of view basically only works for finite enumerations.

It means that there's a single constructor $\mathrm{refl}$ and that you can prove things by path induction by proving things about $\mathrm{refl}$, just like in order to define a group homomorphism out of the free group on one generator you only need to say what happens to the generator. It doesn't mean that every element of the group is the generator. The relationship between $\mathrm{refl}$ and $p$ is the same as that between $0$ and $n!$: they are both terms of $\mathbb{N}$ but one is a constructor and the other isn't.

($p$ does involve $\mathrm{refl}$ in the base case, and furthermore $p$ will reduce to $\mathrm{refl}$ if you instantiate $x$ with any canonical number, just like the definition of $n!$ involves $0$ and $\mathrm{suc}$ and $n!$ reduces to a canonical number for every canonical $n$.)

I think I need to learn more about what you mentioned.  Anyway, thank you both @NaïmFavier and Dan Doel for your patient answers.
